# Как отловить событие перехода Windows в режим сна или гибернации?

Tags: c++, winapi

На Windows версии ниже 10-ки после выхода из сна или гибернации не возобновляется работа веб камеры. Приложению нужно поймать момент перехода в эти режимы (чтобы самостоятельно отключить камеру), и потом поймать выход из этих режимов (чтобы снова её включить).

**Как это сделать?**

Comment: Попробуйте в WindowProc ловить WM_SYSCOMMAND с SC_MONITORPOWER https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx если это не подходит - то нужно ещё искать другие ловушки.

Comment: Очень много программ, игр, и даже как пример, KMPlayer имеют такую проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался! Вдруг кому пригодится:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    switch(uMsg){
        case WM_POWERBROADCAST:
```

а дальше обрабатываем `PBT_APMSUSPEND` из `wParam`